# Best way to handle data hierarchy in vue for a creation form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I'm creating a vue.js app that allows a teacher to create assignments for students. Each assignment is made up of an introductory text and a list of exercises. Each exercise is made up of text as well, plus a list of attachments.

I want to figure out what the best way of creating a form to add an assignment would be from the perspective of getting the most out of Vue's components.

Let's say the entities are represented as objects with the following structures:

```
assignment: {
  text: string,
  dueDate: Date,
  exercises: array
}

exercise: {
  text: string,
  attachments: array
}

attachment: {
  text: string
}
```

The most naive way to accomplish a creation form would be to have something like this:

```
// in <template>
<input type="text" v-model="assignment.text" />
<button @click="addExercise()">Add exercise</button>
<div v-for="exercise in assignment.exercises">
  <input type="text" v-model="exercise.text" />
  <button @click="addAttachment(exercise)">Add attachment</button>
  <div v-for="attachment in exercise.attachments">
      <input type="text" v-model="attachment.text" />
  </div>
</div>
<button @click="submit()">Create assignment</button>

// in <script>
data() {
  return {
    assignment: {
      text: '',
      exercises: [],
    }
  }
},
methods() {
  addExercise() {
    this.assignment.push({
      text: '',
      attachments: [],
    })
  },
  addAttachment(exercise) {
    exercise.attachments.push({
      text: '',
    })
  }
}
```

But this is pretty unelegant as you have everything dumped into a single component.

The first thing I can think of is to have vue components such as `AssignmentForm.vue`, `ExerciseForm.vue`, and `AttachmentForm.vue`.

That way I can handle the data and form markup for each entity separately and compose everything in my main form.

However, I'm unsure how I would manage the state?
I can't just duplicate everything local to my sub-components into my main form, as it would make no sense. But at the same time, what would I be iterating my `v-for`'s over if I don't have a structure to hold all the sub-forms in my main one's local data? I would also need to have a way to collect all the data from my sub-form components and compose it into a single json object to send to my backend upon submitting the form.

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using VeeValidate Nested Arrays

- https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/components/nested-objects-and-arrays

the documentation example was pretty basic, and I expanded on it in my sample project here on codesandbox.io

- code - https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-microservice-72o2s?file=/src/App.vue
- video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUN357fOUN0

we have a final object that looks like this

```
{
  "group-name": "ewqqeeqw",
  "members": [
    {
      "name": "aaron smith",
      "email": "aarons@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "aaron jones",
      "email": "aaronj@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "aaron key",
      "email": "aaronk@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

the benefit I got from vee validate was state management and field validation all provided out of the box. All I needed to do was add item to the array and then the form fields are generated based on the looping

```
     <div>
        <ion-label>MEMBERS</ion-label>
        <div v-for="(m, index) in values.members" :key="index">
          <div>
            <ion-item>
              <Field
                as="ion-input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="name"
                :name="`members[${index}].name`"
                rules="required|min:8"
              />
            </ion-item>
            <span class="error">
              {{ errors[`members[${index}].name`]?.split(".")[1] }}</span
            >

            <ion-item>
              <Field
                as="ion-input"
                type="email"
                placeholder="email"
                :name="`members[${index}].email`"
                rules="required|email"
              />
            </ion-item>
            <span class="error">
              {{ errors[`members[${index}].email`]?.split(".")[1] }}</span
            >
          </div>
          <ion-button
            @click="removeMember(index, values)"
            style="zoom: 0.7; margin-bottom: 8px"
          >
            REMOVE MEMBER
          </ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="padding-top: 12px">
        <ion-button type="submit">SUBMIT</ion-button>
        <ion-button @click="addMember(values)">ADD MEMBER</ion-button>
      </div>
```